# Ignore chat pings found in links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, ping

This chat message:

```
Hi, http://example.com/a/very/long/url/@Doorknob
```

renders as this:

[image]

but it also pings me, due to the `@Doorknob` at the end of the URL.

This message:

```
Here is another sample message.[​](http://@Doorknob)
```

mysteriously sends me a ping:

[image]

This is because the link text consists of a [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), which appears invisible. The `@Doorknob` in the link itself, however, still pings me.

This behavior, when (ab)used by other users, can get extremely annoying.

Could this "feature" be removed, so that pings in URLs do not actually ping people?

Comment: -1 I like this feature. Removing this will break my workflow.

Comment: +1 It used to be funny. Now it's just annoying, with people spamming them and begging for mods to teach them how to do the "MLG stealth ping." It wouldn't take that much to fix, just ignore the @ inside links.

Comment: I don't know if this stealth ping is seen much on the other networks, but people (especially recently) have been using it a lot on PPCG.

Comment: @Calvin no point leaving your comment here after you deleted your question.

Comment: @quartata Is that so? I have seen people that get suspended for repeatedly exploiting a bug after being warned....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will be fixed in chat build 347. Enjoy!

Answer (score 14):

If it's easy to fix, this probably makes sense. But there might exist too many different ways to break chat pings in this way. Suspending people abusing this is likely easier than fixing every corner case.

Users intentionally annoying other users with hidden pings are breaking the rules and making them stop by suspending them is certainly appropriate.

Answer (score -14):

Here is a probable solution to your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Instead of completely disabling the *stealth-ping* feature on chat, the users should have the ability to choose whether or not they want the *stealth-ping* to affect them or not. This means that all *stealth-pings* will appear to users (you can see who is *stealth-pinging* who) if they enable the feature. Those who disabled this feature, however, will not be able to see *stealth-pings*.

If you like *stealth-pings*, then you don't have to disable the *stealth-pinging* feature, but if you don't like *stealth-pings*, then you can disable them.

In this solution, both sides are happy and get what they want.

Comment: Stealth pings are a *bug*, not a feature.

Comment: @Dennis [Then let's make it a feature instead of a bug!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25770064#25770064)

Comment: Why would devs waste their time to implement something properly that can only be used to goof around and annoy people. You *cannot* be serious.