# Simple @mentions do not notify, but direct replies to messages do

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ping

Since at least [December 7](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25989238#25989238), only direct replies to my messages in chat make the notification sound for me. Simple @mentions (like `@El'endiaStarman`) make no sound whatsoever. I've looked but haven't found any similar Meta.SE questions. My computer has been restarted (and my browser, Chrome, has been updated) multiple times since then, so it's a persistent bug. Reloading doesn't work and this is a problem in other chat rooms too. Also, I only get the red notification icons (both in chat and the inbox) when it's a direct reply to a message. I don't know of anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Does the reply count bubble (the one next to your avatar in chat) increment when you're @mentioned (but not replied to)?

Comment: @Doorknob冰: It does not.

Comment: Perhaps related to the `'` in your name, which is often treated as a special character?

Comment: @chirlu: That would be my best guess, but more related to the fact that `'string'` is a common way to denote strings.

Comment: @chirlu was correct - never underestimate the power of a single quote... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed now, sorry about that. The fix for [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270142/ignore-chat-pings-found-in-links) involved treating the chat message as HTML before processing @mentions. This resulted in mentions of your display name being encoded as `@El&#39;endia Starman`. Since an ampersand is not a legal character in a display name (and, by extension, in a mention), only the `@El` part was considered valid. And because a mention needs at least three characters (excluding the `@`) this was simply ignored.