# Stealth pinging, version 2

Tags: bug, chat

When an inline link contains a ping, the ping is effective. Example:

[image]

Pings should be ineffective when in an inline link.

Comment: The original stealth-pinging [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270142/ignore-chat-pings-found-in-links).